# Rails and Realm Mobile Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Just looking for guidance. Is it possible to update Realm Mobile Database objects with a rails app/api and if so how? We want to build a rails web app that can update realm objects but I do not see any documentation on how to achieve this.

Any ideas?

**Example:** A mobile device sends an email to someone with a link that contains params. They click the link, it opens a browser to a rails webpage and in the backend, the rails app takes the params and updates the Realm object with the params.

Is it possible?

Comment: `in the backend, the rails app takes the params and updates the Realm object with the params` -- As far as I know, even using the Realm Object Server, that belongs to the "server-side integration" API, which currently only supports NodeJS and is [available only through the enterprise edition](https://realm.io/pricing/).

Comment: Is there not a REST option?

Comment: Well how does your Rails app intend to change RealmObjects exactly? The ROS sync features in the dev version do inter-device synchronization only, but you can't externally tell it to do things beyond that. Otherwise, the Realm DB on the phone is just a local db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can currently do that with the Enterprise or Pro Edition and the Node.js SDK where you could make a REST API specific to your needs. There is no general REST API (yet).

SEE UPDATE BELOW!

Comment: There is now an official generic way to access the server via GraphQL: See announcement here: https://realm.io/blog/realm-scales-to-the-web/